# Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException

Tags: java, android, syntax, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm attempting to add images from a URL to my android app but for some reason I'm getting an error message stating `Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException.` I believe I have misformatted my code somehow and I could use a bit of assistance figuring out what exactly might be causing this "Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException" error I'm getting.

### SPECIFIC ERROR LINE:

```
Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException: httpRequest = new HttpGet(imgUrl.toURI());
```

### JAVA:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    String url = "http://examplecloudurl.edu/apps/users/results.cfm?lname=FOO&fname=BAR";
    String tr;
    Document doc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog prog;

        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            {
                try {
                    URL imgUrl = new URL(
                            "http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg");

                    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

                    httpRequest = new HttpGet(imgUrl.toURI());

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                            .execute(httpRequest);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                    Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

                    Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
                    for (Element row : tableRows) {
                        Elements cells = row.select("td");
                        if (cells.size() > 0) {
                            title = cells.get(0).child(0).attr("href") + " ; "
                                    + cells.get(0).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(1).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(2).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(3).text();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return title;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String title) {
            super.onPostExecute(title);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(title);

        }

    }
}
```

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO Reimeus:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    String url = "http://examplecloudurl.edu/apps/users/results.cfm?lname=FOO&fname=BAR";
    String tr;
    Document doc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog prog;

        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            {
                try {

                    String imageURL = "http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg";
                    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

                    httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(imageURL));

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                            .execute(httpRequest);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                    Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

                    Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
                    for (Element row : tableRows) {
                        Elements cells = row.select("td");
                        if (cells.size() > 0) {
                            title = cells.get(0).child(0).attr("href") + " ; "
                                    + cells.get(0).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(1).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(2).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(3).text();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return title;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String title) {
            super.onPostExecute(title);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(title);

        }

    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
10-08 15:43:43.590: W/dalvikvm(4017): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d01390)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017): Activity com.example.test.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@413f0a88 that was originally added here
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.test.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@413f0a88 that was originally added here
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at com.example.test.MainActivity$MyTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:54)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1923)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1150)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
10-08 15:43:43.790: E/WindowManager(4017):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO Ravi Thapliyal :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    String url = "http://examplecloudurl.edu/apps/users/results.cfm?lname=FOO&fname=BAR";
    String tr;
    Document doc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog prog;

        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            {
                try {
                    URL imgUrl = new URL(
                            "http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg");

                    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

                    httpRequest = new HttpGet( );

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                            .execute(httpRequest);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                    Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

                    Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
                    for (Element row : tableRows) {
                        Elements cells = row.select("td");
                        if (cells.size() > 0) {
                            title = cells.get(0).child(0).attr("href") + " ; "
                                    + cells.get(0).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(1).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(2).text() + "; "
                                    + cells.get(3).text();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return title;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String title) {
            super.onPostExecute(title);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(title);

        }

    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901): Activity com.example.test.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@413eeed8 that was originally added here
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.test.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@413eeed8 that was originally added here
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at com.example.test.MainActivity$MyTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:53)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1923)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1150)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
10-08 15:40:32.970: E/WindowManager(3901):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is self-explanatory

```
Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException
```

Since, `URISyntaxException` is a **checked** exception you need to `catch` it as well.

```
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This result in: Unreachable catch block for URISyntaxException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Comment: Well, `java.net.URL#toURI() throws URISyntaxException` which `extends Exception`. So, I believe you have to either catch or throw it. One or the other.

Comment: This was just the compiler error you got rid of mate. Can you log the runtime exception stacktrace and post it with your question?

Comment: I apologize - I'm actually getting an error stating "Exception URISyntaxException is not compatible with throws clause in AsyncTask<String,Void,String>.doInBackground(String[]) MainActivity.java" if I remove the exceptions it force closes (any suggestions?)

Comment: When the app force closes doesn't it log the exception stacktrace somewhere? I'm also wondering how does your code compile without the `catch` block? It's a checked exception. Even `URI.create()` catches and wraps it inside the runtime `IllegalArgumentException` for you.

Comment: It will not compile unless I remove the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [`URI#create`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#create%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String imageURL = "http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg";
httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(imageURL));
```

which does not throw a checked exception and can be used when you know the URL has legal syntax

Comment: I tried your suggestion (updated source shown above) now it's no longer crashing - but I don't get the table data or the image in my app when I attempt to run it

Comment: Does the page itself contain table data? Would suggest creating a small standalone application with just the JSoup part for debugging the page content

Comment: I already created the jsoup parser which succesfully grabs the table data - now I'm trying to add the ability to grab an image as well and it's not working (I'm using a different URL and it works successfully.)

Comment: Actually that should be the address of the image not the page - see update